# What is the SecureSocket in AS3?

Tags: sockets, flash, ssl, ftp, tls1.2

I'm using the Socket class to upload a file over FTP to a server. I have been trying to figure out how to implement SFTP and I haven't found any library or API anywhere. But as I was working on it I saw a [SecureSocket](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SecureSocket.html) class. Is this SFTP or FTPS / TLS or something else?

**Update:**
It looks like it's SSL and TLS:

> The SecureSocket class enables code to make socket connections using
>   the Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) and Transport Layer Security (TLS)
>   protocols.

Can I just switch to using this? Is this what I've been looking for all of my life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SecureSocket is a TLS-protected socket. It's not related to SFTP (which is a protocol used on top of SSH, not TLS). SecureSocket can be used for FTP/TLS if you write an FTP client in ActionScipt - then you can use that socket.